# Broadcast receiver for "android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" doesn't work

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to detect camera button pressed by user. I have tried a `BroadcastReceiver` with **android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON** to do it. But it doesn't work. Can someone help me?

In the `manifest` I have this receiver:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".receivers.ActionReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This is my `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class ActionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("receive status", "camera usage");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck.

Comment: onReceive method never get called.

Comment: I've got the same problem, whatever I tried - nothing worked, neither on VD nor PD

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Add this permission in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Add this line in receiver.  `<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />`

```
<receiver
    android:name=".receivers.ActionReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.CAMERA_BUTTON" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: if you are testing in OS 6.0 and above then you need add runtime permission.

Comment: No. I am testing in below OS 6.0 for now

Comment: I haven't seen any error. just the onReceive method is not executed.